# EF Core - Get related entities for a new unsaved entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What would be the best way to get the related entities of a new entity before saving it other than manually loading them by their Ids?
I am following the unit-of-work pattern and trying to get the `Name` property of related entities for logging purposes.

Tried saving entities before creating the log entry inside a transaction but the related entities like Type, Status, etc... are still null. Is it possible to load the related entities in this manner? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public void SaveChanges(User user)
    {
        base.Database.BeginTransaction();

        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
            .ToList();

        base.SaveChanges(); // want to load the related entities after this save

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            this.Add(new LogEntry(entity.Entity)); // log entry uses Name prop of related entities
        }

        base.SaveChanges();
        base.Database.CommitTransaction();
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid TypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid StatusId { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw that there is a `References` property that lists all references. We can iterate through this and load all references. Looks like the related entities can be loaded without even saving the entity.

Not sure if this is a recommended method.

```
public void SaveChanges(User user)
{
    base.Database.BeginTransaction();

    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        foreach (var reference in entity.References)
        {
            entity.Reference(reference.Metadata.Name).Load();
        }

        this.Add(new LogEntry(entity.Entity));
    }

    base.SaveChanges();
    base.Database.CommitTransaction();
}
```